# Get attachment from current email

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, outlook-2013

I am creating a outlook 2013 add-on with C# and Visual Studio 2012 and I want to get the attachment file from the current (open) mail window when a button clicked and save it to a local directory.

Is there any example for this action?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First you would need to get the object of the current mail item. After that you can just loop through the `.Attachments` of the mail item and save them with `.SaveAsFile(filePath)`.

```
var _thisApp = this.Application;
Outlook.MailItem _email;

// Get current email
if(_thisApp.ActiveWindow() is Outlook.Inspector)
{
    Outlook.Inspector insp = _thisApp.ActiveWindow() as Outlook.Inspector;
    _email = insp.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
}
else if(_thisApp.AcitveWindow() is Outlook.Explorer)
{
    Outlook.Explorer exp = _thisApp.ActiveExplorer();
    if(exp.Selection.Count > 0)
        _email = exp.Selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
}

// Loop through the attachments
foreach(Outlook.Attachment attachment in _email.Attachments)
{
    // Some other stuff
    string filePath = @"C:\Saved Attachments\" + attachment.FileName;
    attachment.SaveAsFile(filePath);
}
```

EDIT: Sample to retrieve this.Application

```
private Outlook.Application _thisApp;
private Outlook.Inspectors _inspectors;

// Function in ThisAddin.cs 
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _thisApp = this.Application;
    _inspectors = _thisApp.Inspectors;
    _inspectors.NewInspector +=
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
}
```

Comment: I am getting a error for the line : var _thisApp = this.Application; does not contain a definition for 'Application' and no extension method.....

Comment: @Mantis `this.Application` should be accessible in the ThisAddin.cs. If you are trying to retrieve it from a different location, you could use `Globals.ThisAddin.Application`, though I would suggest you only access it  through public methods in ThisAddin.cs.